# How to change the look of Phonegaps barcode scanner plugin

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova

I have installed this plugin to my PhoneGap project :

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner

It works like a charm. However, I want to be able to have some buttons on whilst the scanner is open to navigate the app. This is so when the app opens the scanner opens straight away so they can scan barcodes straight away and then have a button somewhere where they can go in to the app.

I have tried looking inside the plugin javascript etc but all it has is one javascript file as shown below:

```
cordova.define("phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner", function(require, exports, module) { /**
 * cordova is available under *either* the terms of the modified BSD license *or* the
 * MIT License (2008). See http://opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical for full text.
 *
 * Copyright (c) Matt Kane 2010
 * Copyright (c) 2011, IBM Corporation
 */


var exec = require("cordova/exec");

/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @returns {BarcodeScanner}
 */
function BarcodeScanner() {

    /**
     * Encoding constants.
     *
     * @type Object
     */
    this.Encode = {
        TEXT_TYPE: "TEXT_TYPE",
        EMAIL_TYPE: "EMAIL_TYPE",
        PHONE_TYPE: "PHONE_TYPE",
        SMS_TYPE: "SMS_TYPE"
        //  CONTACT_TYPE: "CONTACT_TYPE",  // TODO:  not implemented, requires passing a Bundle class from Javascript to Java
        //  LOCATION_TYPE: "LOCATION_TYPE" // TODO:  not implemented, requires passing a Bundle class from Javascript to Java
    };

    /**
     * Barcode format constants, defined in ZXing library.
     *
     * @type Object
     */
    this.format = {
        "all_1D": 61918,
        "aztec": 1,
        "codabar": 2,
        "code_128": 16,
        "code_39": 4,
        "code_93": 8,
        "data_MATRIX": 32,
        "ean_13": 128,
        "ean_8": 64,
        "itf": 256,
        "maxicode": 512,
        "msi": 131072,
        "pdf_417": 1024,
        "plessey": 262144,
        "qr_CODE": 2048,
        "rss_14": 4096,
        "rss_EXPANDED": 8192,
        "upc_A": 16384,
        "upc_E": 32768,
        "upc_EAN_EXTENSION": 65536
    };
};

/**
 * Read code from scanner.
 *
 * @param {Function} successCallback This function will recieve a result object: {
 *        text : '12345-mock',    // The code that was scanned.
 *        format : 'FORMAT_NAME', // Code format.
 *        cancelled : true/false, // Was canceled.
 *    }
 * @param {Function} errorCallback
 */
BarcodeScanner.prototype.scan = function (successCallback, errorCallback, config) {

    if(config instanceof Array) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        if(typeof(config) === 'object') {
            config = [ config ];
        } else {
            config = [];
        }
    }

    if (errorCallback == null) {
        errorCallback = function () {
        };
    }

    if (typeof errorCallback != "function") {
        console.log("BarcodeScanner.scan failure: failure parameter not a function");
        return;
    }

    if (typeof successCallback != "function") {
        console.log("BarcodeScanner.scan failure: success callback parameter must be a function");
        return;
    }

    exec(successCallback, errorCallback, 'BarcodeScanner', 'scan', config);
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
BarcodeScanner.prototype.encode = function (type, data, successCallback, errorCallback, options) {
    if (errorCallback == null) {
        errorCallback = function () {
        };
    }

    if (typeof errorCallback != "function") {
        console.log("BarcodeScanner.encode failure: failure parameter not a function");
        return;
    }

    if (typeof successCallback != "function") {
        console.log("BarcodeScanner.encode failure: success callback parameter must be a function");
        return;
    }

    exec(successCallback, errorCallback, 'BarcodeScanner', 'encode', [
        {"type": type, "data": data, "options": options}
    ]);
};

var barcodeScanner = new BarcodeScanner();
module.exports = barcodeScanner;

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Phonegap barcode scanner plugin for Android simply provides an interface between Phonegap and the [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) project. It's the ZXing client for Android which defines the user interface which is displayed while in "scanning mode" and this is done natively (in Java) rather than is Javascript.

To change it, you would need to edit the [library project](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/tree/master/src/android/LibraryProject/src/com/google/zxing/client/android) used by the plugin and make changes to the native UI code there.

Comment: amazing. thanks for the link too, will give me a great start :) just what i needed, thanks